# .NET Core AutoMapper UseAsDataSource or ProjectTo

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I have read in AutoMapper docu that UseAsDataSource should do same job as ProjectTo. However, I have really weird issue:

This code is working:

```
var _query = this.IUnitOfWork.IDataCrmRepository.contacts
                                .Where(w => w.org_id == config_org_id)
                                .UseAsDataSource(this.IMapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                                .For<DTO.contact>()
                                ;
// nov order by optional navigation property (address) which may be null    
_query = _query.OrderBy(o => o.address.city);

return _query.ToArray();
```

This code is not working:

```
var _query = this.IUnitOfWork.IRepository.contacts
                                .Where(w => w.org_id == config_org_id)
                                .ProjectTo<DTO.contact>(this.IMapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                                ;
// nov order by optional navigation property (address) which may be null
_query = _query.OrderBy(o => o.address.city);

return _query.ToArray();
```

I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLIBS29CUR23", Request id "0HLIBS29CUR23:00000006": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier`2 )
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ComputeMap(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ElementAt(TElement[] elements, Int32 count, Int32 idx)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator(Int32 minIdx, Int32 maxIdx)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIPartitionIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

That is the difference?

Okay, I dont have to understand everything, let stay with `UseAsDataSource`. However, when I try to implement async/await, to `return await _query.ToArrayAsync();` it does not work with `UseAsDataSource`, I got another error:

```
    Connection id "0HLIBS9MUOGQR", Request id "0HLIBS9MUOGQR:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

To make this more complicated, when I remove the .OrderBy call, ProjectTo works well with async/await.

Any idea?

Comment: About the ProjectTo, you're probably hitting an EF Core issue. Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Using that you can write a query that fails without AM. Then check the EF Core issues for ideas.

Comment: When I change in ProjectTo part the order by statement to: `_query = _query.OrderBy(o => (o.address != null) ? o.address.city : null);` then it works.. Weird..

Comment: ProjectTo should be the last call in the chain. Otherwise the results will vary depending on the IQueryable provider. Some will translate dto acceses, some won't. UseAsDataSource is supposed to help with that, but I don't know much about it. And there is always expression mapping.